# Checkbox params not creating associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some checkboxes that when clicked will update an associated model. 
The params are being allowed by strong params but not updating the model.

The 'profile' model has one row of 'london' model.

```
<form role="form" action="/profiles" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">

    <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">

    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="profile[bio]">

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="london[south]" value="south">South London</label>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="london[central]" value="central">Central London</label>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="london[north]" value="north">North London</label>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="london[west]" value="west">West London</label>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="london[east]" value="east">East London</label>
      </div>


    </div>      

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My params being shown in rails server log:

"profile"=>{"bio"=>""}, "london"=>{"south"=>"south", "central"=>"central", "north"=>"north"}}

My controller:

```
  class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new

  end

  def create
      @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
      if @profile.save 

        redirect_to '/profiles' 

      else
        render '/profiles'
      end
  end
  private

  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:bio, londons_attributes: [:south, :north, :east, :west, :central])
  end
end
```

Comment: You speak about updating. Do you have an update method in your controller?

Comment: My apologies it was creating not updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
def profile_params
    params[:profile].permit!
end
```